# Changing default behaviour for TCombobox

Tags: delphi, inheritance, subclass, firemonkey, imposter-pattern

I have a project with multiple forms that use TCombobox and i would like to remove the default behavior when a focused combobox receives a Return stroke:

In the **Keydown** of TCustomCombobox:

```
vkF4, vkReturn:
    DropDown;
```

**Q:** How could i remove the functionality for all my forms?

Creating a new custom control that overrides this would mean to much work to recreate all the comboboxes.

**A:** Make an "imposter" subclass :

Found a Duplicate question : [Delphi subclass visual component and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783400/delphi-subclass-visual-component-and-use-it)

I put this code in a unit, and put that unit in the interface/uses of my forms.

```
TCombobox = class(FMX.ListBox.TComboBox)
  protected
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: System.WideChar; Shift: TShiftState);override;
  end;

procedure TCombobox.KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: System.WideChar;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if key=vkReturn then exit;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Subclass using `WindowProc`.

Comment: Thanks to your "sublass" i think i have found the answer, i will try it in my project.